# Build dialogs list from mail database

Tags: mysql, sql

**Description:**
I have a database of private messages users. Scheme:

[image: Database scheme]

For my task is only interested column `owner_user_id` and `viewer_user_id`.
The result of the query `SELECT  owner_user_id, viewer_user_id FROM mail` roughly the:

[Result http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/6dae938eab89faab8f69e683403b1eb2.png](http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/6dae938eab89faab8f69e683403b1eb2.png)

**Problem**:

I need to get a list of **unique dialogues**. 
Namely, from this list(*1), I have to get something like this(*2). 
And this despite the fact that when you build a query, I do not know the identity of any one person.

*1 [Some list http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/1ad2ddeb5afa0d3b97985ab65adaef3f.png](http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/1ad2ddeb5afa0d3b97985ab65adaef3f.png)

*2 http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/1d75c3ee60e73f9874a836b738013c5a.png

**Question**:

How i do it?

*I hope I put the question correctly.*

Comment: You can try SELECT DISTINCT ... or add GROUP BY owner_user_id, view_user_id

Comment: @jeff Please, help me to the build full query from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  LEAST(
    `owner_user_id`,
    `viewer_user_id`
  ) AS first_user,
  GREATEST(
    `owner_user_id`,
    `viewer_user_id`
  ) AS second_user
FROM
  `mail`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jeffs answer (distinct) but need to "order" the tuples in order to unidirect what you call a dialogue.

e.g.

```
SELECT distinct
if(owner_user_id>viewer_user_id,owner_user_id,viewer_user_id), 
if(viewer_user_id>owner_user_id,viewer_user_id,owner_user_id)
FROM mail
```

Rgds
R

Comment: Your query does not work. `Error Code: 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: I changed it since your last answer and tested it on MySQL before posting. If it still does not work, which error do you get this time, and which version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner_user_id, viewer_user_id FROM mail
```

that will get you a distinct list with those two columns

Comment: Not entirely true. Because, there may be such a case: http://screencloud.net/v/1jei